# MySQL, group by in both inner and outer query at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, subquery

Have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT position, AVG(price) FROM products WHERE position IS NOT NULL
AND price < (SELECT AVG(price)+2*STDDEV(price) FROM price)
AND position = 3
```

Nice if you just want to check one position at the time, but I have quite a few positions and I would therefore like to get the data for all the positions at the same time.

i.e. something like:

```
[QUERY]... GROUP BY position
```

But how do I group by position in both the inner and the outer query, so there inner query where clause return a value that matches the right position.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why the -1 rating?

Comment: Hover over the down arrow

Comment: What is position?  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.  Your subquery has no reference to `position`, so you can just aggregate by `position` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `GROUP BY`. To get the average price for each position rather than just for one position, here's what you do.

```
SELECT position, AVG(price) average
  FROM products
GROUP BY position
```

You have a two-sigma exclusion in your query. You need to use the same technique to get the limit for each position. If you want to compute the mean + 2 sigma limit for each position, you need this subquery. (*Note*: It's best to use parentheses in languages like SQL rather than trusting arithmetic operator precedence.)

```
                 SELECT position, 
                        AVG(price) + (2.0 * STDDEV(price)) upper_limit
                   FROM products 
                  GROUP BY position
```

You can then join that query to your top-level select like so

```
 SELECT a.position, a.price
   FROM products
   JOIN (
                 SELECT position, 
                        AVG(price) + (2.0 * STDDEV(price)) upper_limit
                   FROM products 
                  GROUP BY position
        ) b  ON a.position = b.position
            AND a.price < b.upper_limit
```

That gives you the raw data for position / price excluding your outliers.  Do you see how the `ON` clause matches the rows in the main and subquery by position, then filters out the rows where the raw price is above the `upper_limit`? That's the trick.

Then you can aggregate that data with a typical `GROUP BY`.

```
 SELECT a.position, AVG(a.price) average
   FROM products
   JOIN (
                 SELECT position, 
                        AVG(price) + (2.0 * STDDEV(price)) upper_limit
                   FROM products 
                  GROUP BY position
        ) b  ON a.position = b.position
            AND a.price < b.upper_limit
  GROUP BY a.position
```

This layering of subqueries inside queries is why it's called *structured* query language.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't adding `GROUP BY` accomplish what you want?

```
SELECT position, AVG(price)
FROM products p
WHERE position IS NOT NULL AND
      price < (SELECT AVG(price)+2*STDDEV(price)
               FROM price p2
              ) 
GROUP BY position;
```

Or, is there a particular product that you care about?  If so, you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT position, AVG(price)
FROM products p
WHERE position IS NOT NULL AND
      price < (SELECT AVG(price)+2*STDDEV(price)
               FROM price p2
               WHERE p.? = p2.?
              ) 
GROUP BY position;
```

It is just unclear what column should be used for the correlation.

Comment: Thanks, but the top query doesn't limit the stddev to the current position (i.e. each of the positions that we are grouping by).

So instead of filtering stddev for the current position, we filter for the stddev of all the rows in the table.